# Fix the Bat File to make it work in Windows

Tags: bash, batch-file, command-prompt

I'm not familiar with working on Windows command prompt. I've to fix this batch file to make it work in Windows. I understand that this isn't a doubt. But this is stopping my progress and any help would be appreciated.

```bat
ndk-build clean &&
ndk-build APP_PLATFORM=android-15 NDK_LIBS_OUT=./sdk_core_bin NDK_OUT=./sdk_core_obj &&
echo "moving .so files to /src/main/libs" &&
cp -R ./sdk_core_bin/. ./src/main/libs &&
rm -r ./sdk_core_bin &&
rm -r ./sdk_core_obj
```

Comment: You haven't said what you expect it to do, or what the issue you're having is.

Comment: there's no `cp` and `rm` in Windows

Comment: @Lu'uu: Yeah, I'd like to have it translated so that it works in Windows

Comment: @Carcigenicate : On executing line 2, I get this : error: invalid argument '-std=c99' not allowed with 'C++/ObjC++'
make: *** [sdk_core_obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/sdkcore/JniSdkCoreLibrary.o] Error 1

Comment: You probably could have [read](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx) this technet article and figured it out real quickly.

Comment: C99 isn't a C++ standard so obviously it'll be rejected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a batch file. You probably want to convert a bash shell script to a batch file. There are multiple problems with this:

- You can't have `&&` at the end of the line because Windows commands can only be in one line unless you escape the new line with `^`
- Windows path is separated by backslash `\` instead of slash. And it searches in the current folder first so you don't have to use `.` at the beginning of the path
- `echo` is an internal command that doesn't accept parameters so you can't use quotes with it

---

The result might be like this

```bat
ndk-build clean && ^
ndk-build APP_PLATFORM=android-15 NDK_LIBS_OUT=sdk_core_bin NDK_OUT=sdk_core_obj && ^
(echo moving .so files to src\main\libs) && ^
copy sdk_core_bin src\main\libs && ^
rd /s sdk_core_bin && ^
rd /s sdk_core_obj
```

Comment: On executing line 2, I still get this : error: invalid argument '-std=c99' not allowed with 'C++/ObjC++' make: *** [sdk_core_obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/sdkcore/JniSdkCoreLibra‌​ry.o] Error 1 –

Comment: @rsd_unleashed there's no `-std=c99` parameter in the command line, so it's a cmake problem, not batch